# Holes in a Polygon

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

I added this polygon code from this website:
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_donut.html

There is an issue though, the radius is not accurate. So if I measure the distance between 2 cities, then draw this circle, it is way off, and gets worse the larger the circle.

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function drawCircle(point, radius, dir) { 
var d2r = Math.PI / 180;   // degrees to radians 
var r2d = 180 / Math.PI;   // radians to degrees 
var earthsradius = 3959; // 3959 is the radius of the earth in SM

   var points = 1000; 

   // find the raidus in lat/lon 
   var rlat = (radius / earthsradius) * r2d; 
   var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(point.lat() * d2r); 


   var extp = new Array(); 
   if (dir==1)  {var start=0;var end=points+1} // one extra here makes sure we connect the
   else     {var start=points+1;var end=0}
   for (var i=start; (dir==1 ? i < end : i > end); i=i+dir)  
   { 
  var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points/2)); 
  ey = point.lng() + (rlng * Math.cos(theta)); // center a + radius x * cos(theta) 
  ex = point.lat() + (rlat * Math.sin(theta)); // center b + radius y * sin(theta) 
  extp.push(new google.maps.LatLng(ex, ey)); 
  bounds.extend(extp[extp.length-1]);
   } 
   // alert(extp.length);
   return extp;
   }

    var map = null;
    var bounds = null;

    function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(29.10860062, -95.46209717),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                            myOptions);

  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  var donut = new google.maps.Polygon({
             paths: [triangleCoords = [
                        new google.maps.LatLng(-87, 120), 
                        new google.maps.LatLng(-87, -87), 
                        new google.maps.LatLng(-87, 0)],
                     drawCircle(new google.maps.LatLng(29.10860062, -95.46209717), 2000, -1)],";
 
             strokeColor: "#000000",
             strokeOpacity: 0.6,
             strokeWeight: 2,
             fillColor: "#999999",
             fillOpacity: 0.6
 });
 donut.setMap(map);

 map.fitBounds(bounds);


</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "way off"? Could you provide a demonstrator link? Or at least a screenshot?

Comment: The distance between CYQX-EINN is 1715nm. When I type CYQX@1715NM it is about 200 miles short. I did account for conversions. As you check shorter distances like CYQX-CYJT (159nm) its about 3 miles off. The issue is the formula for the radius has a flaw in it.

Comment: So it's not relevant that you are using the radius of the Earth in Statute Miles? 1715NM is 1973SM; 159NM is 182SM. If you are plotting 1715 Statute Miles it will be around 200 miles short of 1715NM.

Comment: I accounted for that, if thats what you are wondering. I tried using a function: circle = [ new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions)], (and the radius is dead on to the meter) but i cant get it to work with paths: []

Comment: The code you presented works in Statute Miles. Where is your accounting?

Comment: I changed it to simplify the code when I uploaded here. 1.15sm=1nm; 200 is ~11% of 1715. 3 is ~1% of 159. Its not a conversion issue. Its something wrong with the formula

Comment: Go to this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons and look at the section labeled "Circle". The radius Formula for this is spot on. But again somehow I could do a hole polygon with this

Comment: What we have here is code which draws a circle of radius 2000 Statute Miles. I reiterate: please supply a demonstrator link.

Comment: http://fpmnky.com/mapsearch.php

Comment: In my code I use: 6371000 meters as the earth radius and convert the NM's to meters (1852)

Comment: I think the cause is the circle calculation you're using is good enough for most purposes but not for aviation. I'll be able to improve it later or tomorrow unless someone else gets there first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better circle-drawing routine may be found by using the "point from bearing" calculations at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html#destPoint

θ is the bearing (in radians, clockwise from north);
d/R is the angular distance (in radians), where d is the distance travelled and R is the earth’s radius

```
var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) + 
              Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                     Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
```

Converting everything to radians and making sure that d and R are both expressed in the same units, we get a circle-drawing routine like this

```
function drawCircle(point, radius, dir, addtoBounds) { 
var d2r = Math.PI / 180;   // degrees to radians 
var r2d = 180 / Math.PI;   // radians to degrees 
var earthsradius = 6371000; // 3959 is the radius of the earth in SM

   var points = 1000; 

   // find the raidus in lat/lon 
   var rlat = (radius / earthsradius) * r2d; 
   var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(point.lat() * d2r); 


   var extp = new Array(); 
   if (dir==1)  {var start=0;var end=points+1} // one extra here makes sure we connect the
   else     {var start=points+1;var end=0}
   for (var i=start; (dir==1 ? i < end : i > end); i=i+dir)  
   { 
      var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points/2)); 
    var lat1=point.lat()*d2r;
    var lon1=point.lng()*d2r;
    var d=radius;
    var R=earthsradius;

    var ex = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) + 
              Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(theta) );
    var ey = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(theta)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                     Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(ex));
      extp.push(new google.maps.LatLng(ex*r2d, ey*r2d)); 
      if (addtoBounds) bounds.extend(extp[extp.length-1]);
   } 
   // alert(extp.length);
   return extp;
   }
```

I have an example at http://www.acleach.me.uk/gmaps/v3/mapsearch.htm where the centre is at CYQX and there's another marker at EINN and a circle of 1715NM radius (expressed as 3176180m). Other circles have been added at radii of 500, 1000, 1500, 2000 and 2500NM.

I've also added a geodesic line between the two points. This crosses the circles at right-angles as expected, which is a check on the accuracy of the circle calculation.

Comment: The hole needs the circle to be drawn in the opposite direction to the containing boundary. Change the direction `-1` to `1`. Once you get to the other side of the world, odd things will happen. In effect (with `1`) you're shading *across* your circle -- from one side of the circle across it to the box boundary on the other side. You may need to reverse the order the lines are used if the distance is more than a quarter of the circumference of the Earth [but I haven't verified that].

Comment: That makes complete sense. I tried both to see the results. I greying issue depends on the Latitude and the Radius Size. I can get up to 11000nm from PAOM and only 6500nm from MMSD; before it gives me issues. Im content with what you have given me, thank you so much.