# Javascript & Google Maps Circle

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Currently the formula I am using is below, but it is less accurate as the Vincenty formula, which you can find on this link:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty-direct.html

My question is, can someone help simplify the javascript code so i can implement it in my formula? I am trying to learn javascript but it is a bit beyond my capabilities.

ex = lat2
ey = lon2

Im thinking the easiest way would be to run through the code and do an array of 360 degrees to calculate the ex/ey coordinates.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function drawCircle(point, radius, dir, addtoBounds) { 
var d2r = Math.PI / 180;   // degrees to radians 
var r2d = 180 / Math.PI;   // radians to degrees 
var earthsradius = 6378137;

   var points = 360; 

   // find the radius in lat/lon 
   var rlat = (radius / earthsradius) * r2d; 
   var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(point.lat() * d2r); 


   var extp = new Array(); 
   if (dir==1)  {var start=0;var end=points+1} // one extra here makes sure we connect the
   else     {var start=points+1;var end=0}
   for (var i=start; (dir==1 ? i < end : i > end); i=i+dir)  
   { 
    var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points/2));//i is number of points + 1 
var lat1=point.lat()*d2r;
var lon1=point.lng()*d2r;
var d=radius;
var R=earthsradius;

var ex = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) + 
                Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(theta));
var ey = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(theta)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                 Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(ex));
  extp.push(new google.maps.LatLng(ex*r2d, ey*r2d)); 
  if (addtoBounds) bounds.extend(extp[extp.length-1]);



   } 
   // alert(extp.length);
   return extp;


   }
```

Here is the direct formula converted to php. I am trying to put this code into the google maps code. The movable type link actually has this code in javascript, but since I know php much better, I converted it over to test it out, this works perfectly.

```
<?php 
 $lat1 = 29.10860062;
 $lon1 = -95.46209717;
 $a = 6378137;
 $b = 6356752.314245;
 $f = 1/298.257223563;  // WGS-84 ellipsoid params
 $brng = 32.8;


 $s = 1796884.48;
 $alpha1 = deg2rad($brng);
 $sinAlpha1 = sin($alpha1);
 $cosAlpha1 = cos($alpha1);
 $tanU1 = (1-$f) * tan(deg2rad($lat1));
 $cosU1 = 1 / sqrt((1 + pow($tanU1,2)));
 $sinU1 = $tanU1*$cosU1;
 $sigma1 = atan2($tanU1, $cosAlpha1);
 $sinAlpha = $cosU1 * $sinAlpha1;
 $cosSqAlpha = 1 - pow($sinAlpha,2);
 $uSq = $cosSqAlpha * (pow($a,2) - pow($b,2)) / (pow($b,2));
 $A = 1 + $uSq/16384*(4096+$uSq*(-768+$uSq*(320-175*$uSq)));
 $B = $uSq/1024 * (256+$uSq*(-128+$uSq*(74-47*$uSq)));
 $sigma = $s / ($b*$A);
 $sigmaP = 2*pi;

 $limit = 100; 
 $counter = 1;

 while ( $counter <= $limit ) {
 $cos2SigmaM = cos(2*$sigma1 + $sigma);
 $sinSigma = sin($sigma);
 $cosSigma = cos($sigma);
 $deltaSigma = $B*$sinSigma*($cos2SigmaM+$B/4*($cosSigma*(-1+2*pow($cos2SigmaM,2))-$B/6*$cos2SigmaM*(-3+4*pow($sinSigma,2))*(-3+4*pow($cos2SigmaM,2))));
 $sigmaP = $sigma;
 $sigma = $s / ($b*$A) + $deltaSigma;
$counter = $counter+1;
};

 $tmp = $sinU1*$sinSigma - $cosU1*$cosSigma*$cosAlpha1;
 $lat2 = atan2($sinU1*$cosSigma + $cosU1*$sinSigma*$cosAlpha1,(1-$f)*sqrt(pow($sinAlpha,2)+ pow($tmp,2)));
 $lambda = atan2($sinSigma*$sinAlpha1, $cosU1*$cosSigma - $sinU1*$sinSigma*$cosAlpha1);
 $C = $f/16*$cosSqAlpha*(4+$f*(4-3*$cosSqAlpha));
 $L = $lambda - (1-$C) * $f * $sinAlpha *($sigma + $C*$sinSigma*($cos2SigmaM+$C*$cosSigma*(-1+2*pow($cos2SigmaM,2))));

 if (deg2rad($lon1)+$L+(3*pi)<(2*pi)) {
 (  $lon2 = (deg2rad($lon1)+$L+(3*pi))-pi);
 } else {
 (  $lon2 = ((deg2rad($lon1)+$L+3*pi))%(2*pi))-pi;}

 $revAz = atan2($sinAlpha, -$tmp);  // final bearing, if required

?>
```

Comment: Does [this question and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027094/holes-in-a-polygon) help?

Comment: I appreciate the time you put into that code. I was very grateful for it, but as I did some digging. I found that the Haversine formula was less accurate for what I need. The Vincenty formula is what I am looking for. I am trying to adapt your code to the new formula. Any help would be great. Thank you again.

Comment: Aha. Didn't match the names up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the link you provided already provides the formula in javascript the hard part is complete, you can just copy it and call it rather than rewriting it into your function.  Just remember to attribute the source.  I removed the variables that were not being used.  Also, I just hard coded `361` into the formula since you were just assigning it to a points variable.  You can change this back if you are going to be passing the number of degrees into the formula.  I separated the `for` loops, to me this is more readable, and I dont think the way you had before was working like you intended it.  When working with degrees and radians I always wrap these conversions into functions since it improves readability.  To do this I hooked them up to the `Number` object in JavaScript using `prototype` as seen here:

```
Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
   //'this' is the current number the function is acting on.  
   //e.g. 360.toRad() == 2PI radians
  return this * Math.PI / 180;
}

Number.prototype.toDeg = function() {
  return this * 180 / Math.PI;
}
```

Not too tough to understand, prototype allows you to extend objects in JavaScript, similar to inheritance in class based languages.  There are plenty of resources online that can help clarify.

Here is the reworked drawCircle function:

```
function drawCircle(point, radius, dir, addtoBounds) {
    //best practice is to use [] rather then new Array(), 
    //both do the same thing.   
    var extp = [];
    if (dir == 1) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 361; i++) {
            //destVincenty function returns a object with 
            //lat, lon, and final bearing.     
            var destPoint = destVincenty(point.lat(), point.lng(), i, radius);

            //add new point 
            extp.push(new google.maps.LatLng(destPoint.lat, destPoint.lon));
            if (addtoBounds) bounds.extend(extp[extp.length - 1]);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 361; i > 0; i--) {    
            var destPoint = destVincenty(point.lat(), point.lng(), i, radius);
            extp.push(new google.maps.LatLng(destPoint.lat, destPoint.lon));
            if (addtoBounds) bounds.extend(extp[extp.length - 1]);
        }
    }

    return extp;
}
```

here is a [fiddle of it working](http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_weaver/CrVHz/).

Comment: Ive determined why Im slow to learning javascript, it does not tell you where the error is like php does. Bryan, It took me about an hour after you gave me this code to get it to work, had to change a few things around ect, the formula is flawless. I added the shading that Andrew Leach provided last week (see the link he posted). Thank you so much for the time.

Comment: Yea, JavaScript debugging can be a pain at times.  There are a number of tools that help locate and debug errors.  Here is a list of some of the most common. Personally, I like Firebug and the IE9 built-in developer tool.   http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/11/18/15-helpful-in-browser-web-development-tools/