# Javascript: Subtract polygons with Latitude and Longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with this operation using Javascript and Google Maps API.

I have a rectangle with their bounds (latitude and longitude).
Also, I have a polygon with their bounds (latitude and longitude for each point).

I need to get a new polygon with the first rectangle without the polygon, so I need to substract the polygon to the rectangle and get the bounds of the new polygon.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to do a cookie cut? So what I mean is the polygon you wish to subtract inside the extent (rectangle)?

Comment: The triangle I want to substract is inside of the main rectangle

Comment: so you want to create a hole effect?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove this part with the shape of the polygon to get the first rectangle without the polygon.

Comment: This will do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027094/holes-in-a-polygon

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a circle inside, else I want the first rectangle without the polygon, for example without another rectangle.

Comment: Please share the code you have so far.

Comment: Essentially, you need to create a polygon with paths that contain 2 arrays of points (rectangle points and triangle points). I will show you an example later if you need. Now is lunchtime! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
// Create a rectangle
var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(33, 3),
        new google.maps.LatLng(44, 25)
    ),
    zIndex: 0
});

// Get the rectangle bounds
var rb = rectangle.getBounds();

// Create a triangle
var triangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillColor: '#00FF00',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    paths: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(39, 4),
        new google.maps.LatLng(34, 24),
        new google.maps.LatLng(43, 24),
        new google.maps.LatLng(39, 4)
    ],
    zIndex: 1
});

// Get rectangle points coordinates (path)
var rectangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(rb.getNorthEast().lat(), rb.getSouthWest().lng()),
    new google.maps.LatLng(rb.getNorthEast().lat(), rb.getNorthEast().lng()),
    new google.maps.LatLng(rb.getSouthWest().lat(), rb.getNorthEast().lng()),
    new google.maps.LatLng(rb.getSouthWest().lat(), rb.getSouthWest().lng()),
    new google.maps.LatLng(rb.getNorthEast().lat(), rb.getSouthWest().lng())
];

// Create polygon from rectangle coords and triangle path
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [rectangleCoords, triangle.getPath()],
    strokeOpacity: 0,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: .6,
    map: map
});
```

*Note: an easier solution would be to create your rectangle like the triangle (Polygon instead of Rectangle) so that you can call `getPath()` on it directly.*

Hope this helps. Below is a working demo.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/m9k4sgxr/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, works fine. I was testing turf.js library to substract polygons, but this works fine for me. Also, I will use Adammck Mask to draw the mask. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You are welcome. Just pasting the links to the libraries you mentioned for further reference: [Turfjs](http://turfjs.org/) - [adammck gmaps-v3-mask](https://github.com/adammck/gmaps-v3-mask/blob/master/README).